# Normalizer condition implies nilpotency.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

A group $G$ is said to satisfy normalizer condition if its every proper subgroup $H$ is properly contained in its normalizer $N_G(H)$. I want to prove that a finite group that satisfies normalizer condition is nilpotent. For this, let $H$ be subgroup of $G$ then $H\triangleleft N_G(H)$. Proceeding in a similar way we have series of normal subgroups
$H_0=H \triangleleft HN_G(H) \triangleleft HN_G(N_G(H)) \cdots \triangleleft HN_G(\ldots N_G(H)\cdots )=G$. Now if we can prove that this series is central then $G$ is nilpotent.But i am not able to do so. Please help me.

Comment: A standard Sylow subgroup argument (sometimes called the Frattini argument) shows that the normalizer of a Sylow subgroup is self-normalizing. This implies that in your case the Sylow subgroups must be normal and the group is direct product of its Sylows.

Comment: Actually sir, i want to avoid this proof.

Comment: Suppose $G$ is a counter example of minimal order. Then every maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal nilpotent. But then the fitting subgroup of $G$ must be $G$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @nex it works, thanks for your reply.